# Books on REST and WCF - Any out there yet?

Tags: wcf, rest

I'm starting to get into WCF and Silverlight development and I've decided on a RESTful architecture.  I need resources now and am looking for some good books.  Can someone recommend any?

Does anyone know if this book: "Learning WCF" by Bustamante ([http://www.amazon.com/Learning-WCF-Hands-Michele-Bustamante/dp/0596101627](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627)) has any REST implementations in there?

Answer (score 4):

See [Colin Jack's review on Restful.net](http://colinjack.blogspot.com/2009/05/book-review-restful-net.html). It doens't cover ReST at all, at most it covers WCF ReST, which is not a RESTful framework to start with.

The book with the warmest reception so far from people that get ReST is Restful Web Services. A mine of information.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260/

And of course, for free you can check Roy's thesis, as it's *the* source of ReST.

Answer (score 2):

[Restful.net](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596519206) I've not read it, but it rated well on Amazon.com

Also,
Not a book, but I thought [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx) was a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished working on a project that was REST based using WCF technology. These are the resources our team referred to for gaining an understanding of REST (Not just from WCF perspective).

1)The REST-discuss group on Yahoo, provides excellent source of information for commonly encountered issues in REST design.(Sometimes even Roy Fielding answers user questions)

2) [Programming WCF by Juval Lowy](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526993/%22) is a good book to understand WCF. Its concise and to the point

3)If you want to know the internals of WCF, one of the best sources is [Aaron Skonnard's service station](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/default.aspx%22.)

4)If you would like to see REST from a platform neutral approach, [then Sam Ruby and Richardson's book is best.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260/%22)

5)To know all the esoteric concepts associated with WCF, [Nicholas Allen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/%20%22) is great.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

***The RESTful CookBook*** is a good place to learn the basics about REST, it is not specific to WCF tho.

http://restcookbook.com/

Answer (score 0):

If java, I would recommend Jersey (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html )